# Errors when creating a wordcloud using the tm and wordcloud packages in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, tm, word-cloud

I am a little unclear about some errors I'm getting using the `tm` package.

I know that the `wordcloud` function in the `wordcloud` package takes a corpus as an argument:

As stated in the documentation:  *(the words you give the function) can either be a character vector, or Corpus*.

So far so good.

With this in mind, I've got some simple code as follows:

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)

corpus  <-Corpus(DirSource("/.../MUSIC"), readerControl = list(language="lat")) readerControl = list(language="lat"))

a <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, c(stopwords("en")), mc.cores=1)
```

I want this next line to give me a wordcloud:

```
wordcloud(a)
```

but instead I get the following error:

```
Error in simple_triplet_matrix(i = i, j = j, v = as.numeric(v),  
nrow = length(allTerms),  :  'i, j, v' different lengths
```

I'm not sure why the corpus is somehow of incorrect dimension.  I was under the impression that the corpus was an acceptable input.

Does anyone have any insight into the nature of either of this error, who has seen this before and perhaps has some ideas about various workarounds?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hard to tell without data.  Since the example in `?wordcloud` works and matches your workflow, that tells me a data problem.  Use `inspect` to see the `Corpus`.  Perhaps missing data, empty rows.  Something out of the ordinary.

Comment: I kept having the exact same problem and I was never able to resolve it. I had that problem on an ubuntu box but not on a debian and ultimately shifted to the debian box but never resolved why that kept happening.

Comment: I should mention I also had that problem with trying to coerce the tm corpus into a dendrogram without even having loaded wordcloud.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a `DocumentTermMatrix` from corpus. try this,

```
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)  
matrix <- as.matrix(tdm)  # changed to term.matrix
v <- sort(rowSums(matrix),decreasing=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)
wordcloud(d$word)
```

**result:**
[image: this is the result]